# docx files in Google viewer

Tags: google-drive

The documentation of Google viewers describe that it [supports](https://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1189935) `.docx` files.

But when I open a .docx file in the Google viewer [nothing is displayed - see here](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=www.cnnct.nl%2FtestViewer.docx)

I can't figure it out what the problem is...or is this a bug of Google viewer?

Has anyone else encountered the same problem?

Comment: I can see `Sadasdasdas docsx` text

Comment: I think it's a browser problem. I use Google Chrome v. 13 and i see   just a grey background. When i open it in firefox i see the text....

Comment: I'm on Google Chrome 13.0.782.220 and i see it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It opens fine in Chrome

[image: docx in GDocs]

Try clearing out your cache - perhaps something is messing up that.